# Python socket "receive data disallowed error"

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, send, recv

I have the following code and it's giving me this error in Python3 in Windows:

OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Could someone help explain why i'm getting this error and how I can avoid it?  What I want to do is start 5 threads with different socket numbers and have them do non-blocking receives.  Thx in advance.

```
import threading
import socket
import os
import errno
import sys
from time import sleep
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)

def worker(port):
    """thread worker function"""
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.setblocking(False)
        s.bind((HOST, port))
        s.listen()
        print('Thread is listening on', port)
        while True:
            try:
                msg = s.recv(4096)
            except socket.timeout as e:
                err = e.args[0]
                if err == 'timed out':
                    sleep(1)
                    print ('No data available')
                    continue
                else:
                    # a "real" error occurred
                    print (e)
                    sys.exit(1)
            else:
                print (msg)


threads = []
for i in range(10001, 10005):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker(i))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: Can you share the error, please?

Comment: Hi the error msg is in my question

Comment: I don't have a solution for you but this link does what you are willing to so check it out: https://pymotw.com/2/select/

Comment: thanks, this does sound like something I would want but is there something that's Windows compatible?